# The property "eventSchedule" is not recognized by Google for an object of type Event

Tags: google, schema.org, structured-data

I used the below code for event scheduling of my event.

But it prompts the below error in Google's Structured Data Testing Tool.

> The property "eventSchedule" is not recognized by Google for an object
>   of type Event.

Can anyone help me on this??

Here is the code that I used:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Event",
  "name": "Example",
  "eventSchedule":
    [
     {
      "@type": "Schedule",
      "startDate": "2016-12-24",
      "endDate": "2017-12-25",
      "frequency": "daily",
      "byDay": ["http://schema.org/Monday","http://schema.org/Tuesday","http://schema.org/Wednesday","http://schema.org/Thursday","http://schema.org/Friday"]
      “startTime": "09:00",
      “endTime": "10:00"
     },
     {
      "@type": "Schedule",
      "startDate": "2016-12-24",
      "endDate": "2017-12-25",
      "frequency": "daily",
      "byDay": ["http://schema.org/Monday","http://schema.org/Tuesday","http://schema.org/Wednesday","http://schema.org/Thursday","http://schema.org/Friday"]
      “startTime": “14:00",
      “endTime": “15:00"
     }
    ]
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it [stated at Schema.org](https://schema.org/eventSchedule), eventSchedule isn't yet implemented into official draft - its implementation is pending. Thats why the validation of it fails.

Comment: Oops! I didn't note that. when it would be approved and implemented??

Comment: huh, good question... This is the github issue, on which this proposal is based: https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/1457 Have no time to dig deeper - whould be nice, if you read further and expand your answer